# JQuery DirtyForms and Bootstrap Nav tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-dirtyforms

My page contains multiple forms in several tabs. Tabs are implemented with bootstrap Navs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) .
Dirty form dialog is non activated when I click a tab anchor (e.g. <a href="#divTab1" class="nav-link" ..). Why ?

My final goal is to have dirtyforms detect the dirty state of a tab and popup the dialog. And if finally user decides to procceed i will clean the dirty state of the leaving tab before switching to the new one.

I tried already the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595666/force-check-dirtyforms-js) and partially it made the job but it pops up the dialog every time I click on any tab.

The environment :

- Dirty forms V2.0
- Dirtyform Dialog Bootstrap V2,0
- Bootstrap V4.6
- JQuery V3.5.1

Thanks in advance